# Does Python maintain function environment after a function is called to implement closure?

Tags: python, closures

I'm studying the materials in [cs61a](http://composingprograms.com/pages/24-mutable-data.html),but the 'withdraw' example in "2.4.4 Local State" gives me an illusion that Python maintains the function environment even after it's call is finished in order to implement closure.But it's seems too costly. So what the mechanism does python takes to implement closure.

Answer (score 3):

When you define an outer functions that returns an inner function:

```
def outer():
    x = 40
    def inner():
        return x + 2
    return inner
```

you have access to the scope of the outer function:

```
>>> func = outer()
>>> func()
42
```

The the value for `x` is stored in the tuple `__closure__`:

```
>>> func.__closure__[0].cell_contents
40
```

Comment: thanks,so It's func's duty to maintain the environment,not the runtime.  so if outer() not assign to any object ,then there's no need to maintain the environment.